# Typings isn't working (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, accounting.js

I have using this lib in my code

[Lib](http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/)

I added typings for it in project like this

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/accounting

And include it in .ts file like this

```
import accounting from "accounting";
```

I see typings under `/node_modules/@types/accounting`

But when I try to run project. My webpack showing this

```
./app/javascript/components/helpers.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'accounting' in '/Users/nemesises/Documents/GitHub/falco-web/app/javascript/components'
 @ ./app/javascript/components/helpers.ts 1:0-36
 @ ./app/javascript/components/itinerary/scripts/hotel_results.ts
 @ ./app/javascript/components/step1/step1.ts
 @ ./app/javascript/components/step1/index.js
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/step1.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3035 ./app/javascript/packs/step1.js
```

tsconfig.json file

```
   {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [ "jquery", "accounting" ],
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "node_modules",
    "vendor",
    "public"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: Could you show your `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: updated my post@kingdaro

Comment: Oh, I just realized this is actually a webpack error, and not a typescript error. One more thing: show the webpack.config.js as well? In a github gist/pastebin if it's big. It might be some issue there with module resolution

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fRYzjHD4 Here it is @kingdaro

Comment: Doesn't look like a standard webpack config, but it should be fine; this one's a headscratcher. I managed to install and use the library in a playground project just fine. I could only think maybe you only installed the types and didn't install the actual module, e.g. `npm install accounting`, but if it's not that... 

Comment: yup, you was right. It fixed it! @kingdaro

Comment: Oh, huh. I'll write up an answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using TypeScript, you have to install the types for the module, *and* the module itself. Preferably like this, so that the types will be added under `devDependencies`, since they're not used at runtime. Add the actual module to use it at runtime, add the types so that TypeScript can check it properly.

```sh
npm install accounting
npm install --save-dev @types/accounting
```